# Using authentication credentials in multiple functions

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I'm writing a script that uses the requests library to obtain API data from a website requiring authentication. From my understanding and testing, the site doesn't seem to use auth-saving cookies, so authentication is required with each request, such as this:

```
page = requests.get('http://a_url.com', auth=(uname, pword))
```

This is fine for what I need *except*, that I have specific tasks split up into separate functions that handle different data in different ways. The only commonality is that they *all* require the username and password (obtained at the command line), so I've ended up with just short of every function taking "uname" and "pword" as their first parameters, followed by any other necessary params:

```
def get_all_projects(uname, pword):
    # function

def get_single_project(uname, pword, project_name):
    # function

def get_select_projects(uname, pword, projects):
    for project in projects:
        get_single_project(uname, pword, project)

# Etc...
```

Aside from turning the script into a class, is there any other way to deliver the credentials to the functions that need them without having to parameterize them? Requests.Session() won't work, since as stated above I need to include the auth with each call to get. I feel like a decorator would fit the situation well, but I don't understand them well enough yet to be able to confirm that belief.

Comment: What's wrong with turning the script into a class? For me that's the best way to go. A decorator would need to store both values somewhere, probably globals, so I don't feel that fit your needs.

Comment: The documentation for requests sessions http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/ says 'Sessions can also be used to provide default data to the request methods. This is done by providing data to the properties on a Session object:' and then contines by giving an example of adding auth to the session, so it will be provided with every request `s = requests.Session()   
s.auth = ('user', 'pass')`

Comment: @cdonts The other requirements for making it a class are (imo) unnecessary for the scope of what my script is intending. Not that making it a class would _bad_ exactly, I'm just trying to avoid the excess fluff if I can for this one.

Comment: @barny I can't believe I missed that in the docs! I'll do some more looking into that since that's basically exactly what I was looking for. I'll report back with results when I can. On that note though, I believe this means I just pass the session to each function instead of the auth though?

Comment: You use the session to make every request.

Comment: I added an answer based off your pointing out of that section I missed in the docs, it did indeed give me what I needed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @barny pointed out, I missed the fact that you *can indeed* pass authentication to a requests.Session() via the following (from the docs and barny's comment):

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (uname, pword)
```

so my url request from the op can now just be:

```
page = s.get('http://a_url.com')
```

with the auth automatically included as long as the session is active.

Along with that, my functions can now be condensed to just using the session object as a param instead of the username and password each time:

```
def get_all_projects(s):
    # function

def get_single_project(s, project_name):
    # function

def get_select_projects(s, projects):
    for project in projects:
        get_single_project(s, project)

# Etc...
```